# How do I associate linux scsi device names with disk devices?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, software-raid, scsi

I have a CentOS 4.x server running software raid.  The server has two scsi disks in hot-swap trays.  mdadm reports that the raid has failed, and so I would like to replace it.

I examine /proc/mdstat, which tells me my two raid devices have components on disks sda and sdb.  It also tells me that sdb is the one that failed.

I examine /proc/scsi/scsi, which tells me I have two physical devices, at SCSI IDs 0 0 0 0 and 0-0-1-0.

Because I want to do the change hot, I assume that sdb is 0-0-1-0.  So I say:

```
# echo "scsi remove-single-device 0 0 1 0" > /proc/scsi/scsi
```

...and the computer barfs because sda has just been removed, leaving the system with no valid drives.

Now upon reflection, the way I got into this mess was the last time a drive failed, it was sda/0-0-0-0, and I did it the old-school way -- stop the computer, remove the dead drive, then boot off of the survivor in it's old slot.  This left me with a computer that thought that sda was 0-0-1-0.  I then obtained and inserted, hot, a replacement, and added it like so:

```
# echo "scsi add-single-device 0 0 0 0" > /proc/scsi/scsi
```

...which worked, which meant I could apply a disk label, partition, and reconstruct my raid arrays.  This also meant that the computer thinks that sdb is 0-0-0-0.  Now sdb dies again (350 days later, but that's another issue)  and I have forgotten all this.

So.  Assuming that both my memory and my records keeping skills are inadequate for reminding me that this has happened, is there a way that in future can I compare the scsi device names (0-0-$n-0) and associate them with named devices (sd$x)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look in `/sys/block/sda/device, which will have a symlink starting with scsi_device that identifies the device:`

```
$ ls -d /sys/block/sda/device/scsi_device*
/sys/block/sda/device/scsi_device:0:0:0:0
```

Or you can look in `/sys/bus/scsi/devices:`

```
$ ls /sys/bus/scsi/devices/
0:0:0:0  1:0:0:0  2:0:0:0  3:0:0:0  7:0:0:0  8:0:0:0
```

Each entry here represents a SCSI device.  Inside each directory is a symlink starting with block: that identifies the corresponding block device:

```
$ ls -d /sys/bus/scsi/devices/0\:0\:0\:0/block*
/sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:0:0/block:sda
```

Comment: CentOS 4.x does not have /sys/blocl/sd?/device/scsi_device* file(s).  But it does populate /sys/bus/scsi/devices/0\:0\:?\:0/block correctly.  Thank you.